# How to resolve the following in Node.js stream, fs, utils persisting even after installing packages

Tags: node.js, stream, resolve, node.js-fs

I have installed the following packages, e.g. fs, utils, and stream, although others like fs/promises cannot be installed. However, the error still persists.

Things done :
I have installed the packages
I have resolved them in Webpack
I have changed my node version.
Error persists

1. ./node_modules/hardhat/internal/artifacts.js
   Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs/promises'

2./node_modules/hardhat/internal/util/fs-utils.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs/promises'

3./node_modules/undici/lib/core/util.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'stream/web'

4./node_modules/undici/lib/fetch/body.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'util/types'

Comment: Things like the `fs` module cannot be used in a module that will be run in the browser.  So, if you're trying to use webpack to make code that will run in a browser, you cannot use the `fs` module or any modules that depend on the `fs` module in that code.  The browser does not support the depth of libraries that nodejs does so you can't just run any nodejs code in the browser.

Comment: Can you suggest some suitable methods and approaches? Thanks for the answer. I appreciate it! @jfriend00

Comment: The only approach is to NOT use the `fs` module or any other module that depends on it for code that runs in the browser.  There is no substitute as the browser (for security reasons) does not offer the capabilities that the `fs` module does.  There is webstream support in the browser so if that's what you're really trying to use and the origin of the issue here, then the code needs to be written in a way that uses the browser's implementation directly (not through nodejs libraries).

Comment: Okay, great then, I will try these options. Really appreciate the insight and the depth of the explanation (of the problem). I will try the other webstream support option and see.Thanks a lot!